# Set PikaChoose images to be hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url, slider

I need to set PikaChoose images (that ones on stage) to be clickable - just as usual banners. I was looking for this answer so much I've been wondering is it even possible - I couldn't find an answer on official site either.

My code is:

```
<ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="PromocjeRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <li><a href="<%#Eval ("Url") %>"><img src="./timthumb.php?src=images/Promocje/<%#Eval ("Banner") %>.jpg&h=<%=wys %>&w=920" /></a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

It is written in C# ASP, and the link's href is in <%#Eval ("Url") %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use different library, but it seems that this feature was fixed in the latest version of PikaChoose (or at least it worked when updated the jQuery file).